# What is the physics behind the movement of the split-finger fastball in baseball?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, projectile, aerodynamics

A split-finger fastball, or a splitter, is a baseball pitch thrown like a fastball with an v-shaped split finger grip. When thrown correctly, it moves like a fastball, straight in the air, but suddenly drops as it approaches the home plate. Here is a [gif](https://giant.gfycat.com/PinkExcellentHectorsdolphin.gif) of how the pitch moves.

[image]

I've searched various sources that explain the reasons, which aren't very convincing to me:

***Reason 1:*** *The ball has a reduced backspin as compared to a regular fastball, and hence falls due to a stronger gravity than the upward [Magnus force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect).*

This does not convince me. This scenario should result in a constant force on the ball throughout it's path of motion, and the descent should be gradual, and not be seen at the end of the pitch.

***Reason 2:*** *The slight backspin on the ball forms ripple vortexes as it travels through the air, which eventually leads to the ball developing a topspin, which causes the ball to drop*

This reason seems to be more plausible, and can explain why the ball drops suddenly and not gradually. However, I'm not so convinced if this is a very accurate reasoning or not. A pitch known as the knuckleball, thrown with very little spin, utilizes these vortices to make the ball move unpredictably. I'm not certain if the slight backspin allows the pitcher to control the effect these vortices have.

What is the most accurate explanation for why a splitter moves the way it does?

Comment: " but suddenly drops as it approaches the home plate".....Do you have any evidence for the cited discontinuous nature of the ball's trajectory? Say, a side view?

Comment: @DJohnM I'm afraid finding a gif like that wont be easy. These gif are made from the video recorded by the cameras that broadcast on TV, and this is the standard view for a pitch. I'm quite sure that this is how the pitch moves, as many baseball experts claim the ball moves "like a ball rolling off a table".

Answer (score 1):

It certainly does not have topspin at any point. The first reason is correct. It has less backspin and therefore appears to drop. The camera angle from behind the pitcher is deceiving. Although it appears to drop off suddenly, it is more gradual than it appears. A straight fastball defies gravity quite a bit, as does a split fingered fastball, because they both have backspin. The splitter just does not defy gravity nearly as much.  The best splitters have relatively high velocity to mimic a fastball, but reduced backspin to get the “drop” action.

Answer (score -1):

First off, there is no consistent answer to this question because there is no consistent  pitcher, muscle power and slight variations in the manner in which the baseball is thrown will always produce different results from each throw.

It seems to depend on the pitcher releasing the ball closer to the end of the arc of the swing on it than he normally would, he keeps his wrist loose and imparting a slight downward vector just before releasing it.

Based on [Splitters](https://www.drivelinebaseball.com/2016/11/spin-rate-what-we-know-now/), which has stats, (and lots of 'em) and various YouTube videos, particularly  [Throwing Splitters](https://m.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=gfwCmqfF36s)